# Allow/Force spring-cloud to use HTTPS

Tags: spring-cloud

[image]

Let assume that we have above simple system configuration.

- Spring Zuul as a proxy
- Spring Eureka as discovery for all system elements
- And 2 services Foo/Bar with business logic

What system can do is:

- **Zuul** base on request type is able to forward request to **foo** or **bar** services.
- So more in some cases the **foo** can contact with **bar** via @FeignClient.

**The question is: How make whole communication among elements secure so using HTTPS? And maybe which obsoletes others, is it worth? Wouldn't be better assume that all what is behind zuul can safely communicate via HTTP?**

As question is quite complex I have divided it to smaller parts and added my current knowledge (which may be incorrect). To achieve expected result I think I need to solve following 4 points:

**1. Register services in Eureka using HTTPS:**

Based on docs I manage to get below config, but is it enough?

`eureka.instance:
        nonSecurePortEnabled: false
        securePortEnabled: true
        secure-port: ${server.port}`

**2. Force @FeignClient to use HTTPS**

It is what I do not know at all... Should I use in each @FeignClient the "https" information? So for example should my **Foo** service have defined

`@FeignClient("https://bar")`

Or I can force @FeignClient to use HTTPS by default via setting in application.yml:

```
ribbon.isSecure: true
```

Or there is 3rd proper option?

**3. Force Zuul to accept only HTTPS requests**

Do I need to make something more besides?

```
@Configuration
class ZuulConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.portMapper().http(${nonSecurePort}).mapsTo(${securePort});
        ...
    }
}
```

**4. Allow Zuul to forward HTTPS requests**

After setting all above elements do I need to make any special changes in configuration on zuul except following?

```
zuul:
  ignored-services: '*'
  routes:
    foo:
      path: /foo/**
    bar:
      path: /bar/**
```

Comment: If you want everything to communicate via `https` than I think doing 1,3, and 4 should be enough.  If you do 3 than Feign will not use Ribbon (and hence not use Eureka), just do `@FeignClient("serviceName")`.

It might be fine to terminate SSL at Zuul but that is for you to decide.